# How to force reboot from user login screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, reboot

If I have a computer with windows 7 on it, that is in the user login screen,

how do I force a reboot?

Pressing the "Shut down" button won't help since it is set to go to stanby in that occasion (but then again the user login screen would reappear)

Comment: There should be a power options on the login screen.  If shutting down your computer only places it in hibernation then you have power mangement configuration problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to *force a reboot*, and the option to cleanly power down or reboot is not available, and a tap of the power button sends the device to standby, then hitting the reset switch, holding in the power button for 5 seconds, or removing power is the only option. It's a poor practice for admins to remove the ability for a user to power down cleanly, because the end result is that users tend to do a hard reboot out of necessity, potentially causing data loss or other issues.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is a hard reboot or a hard reset by holding down the power button for 5 to 6 seconds or unplug the cable or the battery.

Comment: This is a very bad way to do it...  I highly recommend AGAINST that!

Comment: @Taegost, can you please tell us a better way?

Comment: This can cause data loss.  This is a horrible idea.

Comment: @Ramhound, got any better solution?

Comment: That is the only thing that worked. I lost data. My bad. I should not have used windows in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Just click the dropdown arrow attached to the shutdown button, and choose restart.

Comment: Many domain attached computers will have this option disabled via group policy, but still a good option +1.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is remotable and you have LMI, then just remote to it and execute a restart command from LMI.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, you could also pull the plug, this would force it to shutdown/startup mind you you may need to run startup repair after.

Comment: This is a very bad way to do it... I highly recommend AGAINST that!

Comment: @Taegost, can you please tell us a better way?